# How to access object propety when it has special characters in PHP

Tags: php, object

Please help me get "@odata.nextLink" property value.
I tried to `b2cUser->@odata.nextLink` but it has syntax error.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need add the property into "{}".

```
$b2cUser->{'@odata.nextLink'}
```